# How can i deleted a file that is using by IronOCR process in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for my bad English.
I would like to extract text from a image then delete it. Can you show me how to stop Ocr process after i extracted text from file to delete it?
this is my code

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testtool.png");
        var ocr = new AutoOcr();
        result_text.Text = ocr.Read(image).ToString();
        string textforClipboard = result_text.Text.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetText(textforClipboard);
        //File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testtool.png");
```

This is the error:
System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testtool.png' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: Dispose of the `image` instance when you're done with it.

Comment: Don't use `Image.FromFile()` (possibly, ever), do something like `Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("File Path")), true);`. This way you don't lock the file on disc and you load the Image *properly*.

Comment: tks you very much, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

An image is Disposable. Before you delete files that contains Images, you should Dispose all Images that are extract from the file.

Make it good practice: always consider `using` when you are dealing with an IDisposable. This way, you can be certain that whatever happens: the object is disposed when you don't need it anymore, even after exceptions.

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testtool.png"))
{
     // do with the image what you need to do
     // Is AutoOcr also IDisposable?
     using (var autoOcr = new AutoOcr())
     {
         ...
     }
     // object autoOcr is disposed
}

// object image is disposed. You can delete the file that contains this image
System.IO.File.Delete(...);
```